# Flux of photons and optical depth

Tags: optics, visible-light, atomic-physics

Given a laser beam which is emitting a certain flux of photons $F$, with an average photon energy $E$, sent on a detector through a medium of optical depth $\tau$, how is possible to estimate the flux of the photons arriving at the detector?

Comment: Welcome to PSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' [quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know your initial flux $F_0$ and the optical depth $\tau(\lambda)$ at your photon wavelength $\lambda$ corresponding to photon energy $E = \frac{h \cdot c}{\lambda}$. Then the flux $F$ of photons arriving at detector distance $d$ is according to Beer-Lambert law: $$F = F_0 \cdot e^{-\tau(\lambda)} = F_0 \cdot e^{-\sigma(\lambda) \cdot \rho \cdot d}$$
(Note, instead of the optical depth $\tau$ you often find the optical density $\sigma$ in Beer-Lambert. However, for a given extinction distance $d$ and constant absorber density $\rho$ along the light path, the relation is just $\tau = \sigma \cdot \rho \cdot d$).